# Shiny, can't choose variable of a selected dataset

Tags: r, shiny

In my app I want user to choose between two dataset (mtcars and iris), then to choose one variable from previously chosen dataset. The app will show the summary of that variable.

I can choose the dataset, however a problem arises when I'm trying to choose the variable - everytime I choose something, it returns to the first column available (eg. while choosing Iris as a db I can see only Sepal.Length). For a brief moment summary can be seen for that chosen variable

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
db_cars <- mtcars
db_iris <- iris

# Define server logic required to summarize and view the selected dataset
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    simple_name <- eval(as.symbol(paste(input$dataset))) 
    observe({
      updateSelectInput(
        session,
        "variable", 
        choices = colnames(simple_name[1:ncol(simple_name)]) 
      )
    })
    simple_name %>% pull (input$variable)
  })
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- datasetInput()
    summary(dataset)
  })
})

# Define UI for dataset viewer application
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Shiny Text"),
  sidebarPanel(    
    selectInput("dataset", "Choose dataset", 
                choices = c("db_cars", "db_iris")),
    selectInput("variable", "Choose variable", 
                choices = ""),
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the reactive element into two parts. One for the data selection, and one for variable selection.

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  currentdata <- reactive({
    simple_name <- eval(as.symbol(paste(input$dataset)))     
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "variable", 
      choices = colnames(simple_name[1:ncol(simple_name)]) 
    )
    simple_name
  })

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    currentdata() %>% pull(input$variable)
  })
  
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    dataset <- datasetInput()
    summary(dataset)
  })
})
```

They way each is only dependent on one input value so you don't run into trouble trying to change the dataset when you are trying to change just the varible.